# Is it possible to know the source(e.g. Google Play) of Android app?

Tags: android, google-play, android-applicationinfo

Is it possible to check whether an application was installed via Android market (Google Play Store) or by other means?

Basically what I want to know is whether an application is genuine or not. If the source of installation of an app is Play Store, then we know that the application named com.dropbox.android is the actual dropbox application but if the source is not Play Store, then anyone could have created an android app with same package name and installed it on device.

Comment: Interesting question, as far as I know the answer is no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might be the same question as in [How to know an application is installed from google play or side-load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load) 
Try and see if the provided solution works for you.

Comment: works! Thank you! :) I couldn't find that question when I searched.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a way to detect this. However, to keep it safe, I would suggest you to always disable `Unknown sources` in *Security* or *Development* sections under *Settings* to avoid any non-market apps being installed.