# Hide apk file such that no one can download it from play store using web?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

i need to know how to hide apk file so that no one from web can download apk file using some apk downloading websites e.g https://apkpure.com  and so on.

Comment: Doubtful if an APK being made available on multiple non-google play websites can be prevented. That being said, you can check if the application is installed via the Google Play store or side-loaded, etc by looking at a few answers in this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/10809438/450534 and prevent the app from functioning at all for example. ;-)

Comment: thanks for feedback. i will try that  @IceMAN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way you could prevent users to download the apk file. The best solution I guess is to [obfuscate](https://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) it. :)