# How to know whether android app is install from play store without using packageInstaller

Tags: android

Is it Possible to know whether android app is install from play store without using  packageInstaller? Every Other question is related to packageInstaller which any one can edit but my question is without using packageInstaller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know an application is installed from google play or side-load?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load)

Comment: Have you found the app you're looking for in the Play Store?

Answer (score 1):

You should use **[InstallReferrerReceiver](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver)**.
Create and register `BroadCastReceiver` like in the article.
Here is my simple example:

```
public class InstallReferrerReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String FROM_SPECIFIC_FEED = "FROM_SPECIFIC_FEED";
    public static final String MAIN_FEED_ID = "MAIN_FEED_ID";

    private static final String REFERRER = "referrer";

    private static final String SOURCE = "utm_source=";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String referrer = intent.getStringExtra(REFERRER);
        //"utm_source=24news.com.ua&utm_medium=js&utm_term=fee";
        //"utm_source=12&utm_medium=js&utm_term=fee";
        String mainFeed = extractMainFeed(referrer, false);

        if (mainFeed != null && mainFeed.length() > 0) {
            try {
                setMainFeed(context, Integer.parseInt(mainFeed));
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private String extractMainFeed(String referrer, boolean toEnd) {
        if (!toEnd) {
            try {
                return referrer.substring(referrer.indexOf(SOURCE) + SOURCE.length(), referrer.indexOf("&"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return extractMainFeed(referrer, true);
            }
        } else {
            try {
                return referrer.substring(referrer.indexOf(SOURCE) + SOURCE.length());
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void setMainFeed(Context context, int mainFeedId) {
        PreferenceManager.getInstance(context).setMainFeedId(mainFeedId);
        Intent fromSpecificFeed = new Intent(FROM_SPECIFIC_FEED);
        fromSpecificFeed.putExtra(MAIN_FEED_ID, mainFeedId);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(fromSpecificFeed);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can set any install Referral through adb

Answer (score 0):

In Packagemanager chek for getInstallerPackageName, this method will give you the information.

Comment: But it is possible to change installer package name then how can we detect??