# Track downloaded APK from unofficial store

Tags: android, google-play

So we have an unofficial store where apk will be available for download. Is there any way I can track whether the apk was downloaded from that unofficial store or not. Basically our application is available on both Google Play and Our own website (unofficial store). And we want capture rating. So if the application is not downloaded / installed through google play then I want to know how I can redirect the user to capture the rating.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load , this is what you are looking for i guess?

Comment: Hey thanks, I will test and will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below line code to get package name from where apk is downloaded `PackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()`

for example google play will return "com.android.vending".