# Hello to prevent my app sharing through third party app like shareIt?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello I am creating paid application on flutter so please tell me how I can prevent my application sharing through third parties app like share it I don't want someone shareit only download from playstore & App Store using paid method after application is download it will unable to share anyone?

Comment: hey what's problem you have it valid question why negative vote it

Comment: You cant prevent the app from share but you can check if the app is sideloaded or installed from the play store 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load